# unable to install "weak" when i am installing npm packages in node application?

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

i have setup an `Aws Ec2` instance to host my Node.js application. After cloning the project from git repo when i am installing all packages using `sudo npm i` so before the completion of packages installation it gives an error like this

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 
'/home/ubuntu/directory-server/node_modules/weak/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-1021-aws
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" 
"/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/directory-server/node_modules/weak
gyp ERR! node -v v11.10.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
"name": "faunder",
"version": "0.0.1",
"description": "Faunder",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"clean": "rimraf -rf build && mkdir build",
"build": "babel src -d build && npm run build:copy",
"build:copy": "cp src/conf/config.ini build/conf/config.ini && cp -r 
src/static build/ && cp src/api/handlers/logo-orange.png 
build/api/handlers/logo-orange.png",
"build:deploy": "npm run clean && npm run build && pm2 start 
build/index.js",
"start": "nodemon src/index.js --exec babel-node --presets env"
 },
"author": "shayan.ahmed@utf-labs.com",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"count-files": "^2.6.2",
"csvjson": "^5.0.0",
"csvtojson": "^2.0.8",
"dynamic-html-pdf": "0.0.4",
"express": "^4.16.2",
"fs-extra": "^7.0.1",
"htmltopdf": "0.0.8",
"image-to-base64": "^2.0.1",
"ini": "^1.3.5",
"json2csv": "^4.1.6",
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.10",
"md5": "^2.2.1",
"moment": "^2.21.0",
"mongodb": "^3.0.0-rc0",
"mqtt": "^2.14.0",
"multer": "^1.4.1",
"mysql2": "^1.5.1",
"node-async-loop": "^1.2.2",
"node-dir": "^0.1.17",
"node-schedule": "^1.3.0",
"nodemailer": "^4.6.8",
"nodemon": "^1.18.1",
"rimraf": "^2.6.3",
"save-dev": "^2.0.0",
"sequelize": "^4.27.0"
 },
 "devDependencies" : {
  "babel-cli" : "^6.26.0"
 }
}
```

when i run this command `sudo npm i` so this command completes the package installation but failed in between at this point

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 
'/home/ubuntu/directory-server/node_modules/weak/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-1021-aws
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" 
"/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/directory-server/node_modules/weak
gyp ERR! node -v v11.10.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

and then it continues to finish the installation of rest of the packges. But due to failure at this point when i run my node application so it throws an error like this

```
 Error: Cannot find module 'weak'
 0|index  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
 (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:613:15)
 0|index  |     at Function.Module._load 
 (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:25)
 0|index  |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:17)
 0|index  |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
 0|index  |     at new D (/home/ubuntu/directory- 
 server/node_modules/dnode/index.js:28:20)
 0|index  |     at module.exports (/home/ubuntu/directory- 
 server/node_modules/dnode/index.js:8:12)
 0|index  |     at /home/ubuntu/directory- 
 server/node_modules/phantom/phantom.js:174:13
 0|index  |     at Server.handler (/home/ubuntu/directory- 
 server/node_modules/shoe/index.js:22:9)
 0|index  |     at Server.emit (events.js:197:13)
 0|index  |     at App.emit (/home/ubuntu/directory- 
 server/node_modules/sockjs/lib/sockjs.js:182:27)
 0|index  |     at Session.emit_open (/home/ubuntu/directory- 
 server/node_modules/sockjs/lib/transport.js:107:23)
 0|index  |     at processTicksAndRejections 
 (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:9) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

Comment: You can try to change your node version. It may helps.

Comment: but this line of error 'gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir' seems that it's permissions error? don't you think this is permissions error?

Comment: gyp error are often cryptic. Last time I had such an issue it was because I was using the wrong node version, so maybe it can help, but not sure :)

Comment: Can you tell me what command should i use to update node version on ubuntu instance on Aws EC2?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to folder permission in EC2.
Here are the possible solution that you can try

First give `chmod 777` rights to  your folder that clone from **git** then
try `sudo npm install`

Also update your Node version to `8.x` ,if above issue still not resolve